# How can i get the position of a record in a mongo query / collection?

Tags: mongodb

Say, for example, I have a leaderboard in MongoDB. The following query would get a segment of the leaderboard:

```
db.leaderboard.find().sort({ score: -1 }).limit(30)
```

What if i had a leaderboard entry, with an `_id` of, say, `a`:

```
db.leaderboard.find({ _id: 'a' })
```

How would i go about finding the position of that record on the leaderboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy. First, find the score for the target record:

```
db.leaderboard.find({ _id: 'a' }, {score : 1, _id : 0});
```

Then count all the documents that have score greater than the target score:

```
db.leaderboard.find({ score : { $gt : 100 /* targetScore */ } }).count();
```

Your position will be +1 of the count.
One caveat: if there are multiple documents with the same score as the target score your position will probably be "wrong".

An example: when you sort your documents by using sort and you have 3 documents. Let's say the they are in 7,8 and 9 "position". Your document with `_id : 'a'` can be on any of these "positions".

Comment: thanks! i think that should do it. In this case it's highly unlikely the scores will be equal.

Comment: In fact, i think the equal scores thing can be accounted for with only one extra query - get all entries with that same score, and order them by something specific (create date, username, email address etc.), then make sure the actual leaderboard is ordered by that same thing.

Comment: Is there any way to solve documents with same score?